# Email send django returning error when details comes from database

Tags: python, django, database, django-views, django-admin

I have A FUNCTION TO SEND MAIL IN django helper file my function is givenm below

```
def mail_send(data):
    result = {}
    getTemplate = EmailTemplate.objects.filter(pk=data['type']).first()
    if getTemplate != None:
        templates = Template(getTemplate.template)
        config = EmailConfiguration.objects.filter(pk=1).first()
        context = Context(
            {
                'name': data['name'],
                'password': data['password'],
                'site_name': config.site_name
            }
        )
        msg_plain = 'Login Details ' + data['name'] + ' / ' + data['password']
        msg_html = templates.render(context)
        EMAIL_USE_TLS = config.tls
        EMAIL_HOST = config.host
        EMAIL_HOST_USER = config.from_email
        EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = config.password
        EMAIL_PORT = config.port
        mail = send_mail(
                    data['msg'],
                    msg_plain,
                    EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                    [data['email']],
                    fail_silently=False,
                    html_message=msg_html,
                )
    else:
        result['msg'] = 'Template Not Found .Unable to send Email..'
        result['status'] = False
```

its returning me the error like : [Errno 111] Connection refused

but when i put all this setting in settings.py its working fine with me but i dont want this i want to come from database and send a mail please suggest me i am stuck here from last day .i am newbe in django so its getting verry difficult to me

Comment: Please share your settings.py file, it seems that your mail settings are not correct.

Comment: This is what my question about because i dont want settings to come from the settings .py file i want this from database custom mail details.

Comment: Check type of config.tls (should be boolean) and config.port(should be integer).

Answer (score 0):

This is a very weird setup and probably not the best practice to follow.

Nevertheless, Django still has your back.

Let's look at the signature of `send_mail`

```
send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list, fail_silently=False, auth_user=None, auth_password=None, connection=None, html_message=None)
```

Sadly we can't give it the host here, but we can give it a connection.

```
from django.core.mail import get_connection

def mail_send(data):
    ....
    connection = get_connection(
        host=config.host,
        port=config.port,
        username=config.from_email,
        password=config.password,
        use_tls=config.tls,
    )
    mail = send_mail(
        data['msg'],
        msg_plain,
        config.from_email,
        [data['email']],
        fail_silently=False,
        html_message=msg_html,
        connection=connection,
   )
```

Comment: Error in terminal ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.core.email'

Comment: I'm so sorry... it was a typo... should be `from django.core.mail import get_connection`.